# Finish an activity after starting a service through it

Tags: android, service

I am starting a service from an activity in its onCreate() and then finish the activity in onStart() method. When I run the application, it shows dialog saying "Unfortunately, the app has stopped" but my service is also being called and working as expected. what shall I do so that I do not get the dialog box??

My activity class code is :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
    startService(intent);

}

@Override
protected void onStart(){

    MainActivity.this.finish();

}
```

Comment: try moveTaskToBack(true) and then call this.finish() after startService(...) line

Comment: It worked really great. Thanks! But can you tell me what was the problem and how it got solved by this? @sector11